# Point process representation of the limit of ACF

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, notation, point-processes

I am struggling with **Theorem 3.5** from the paper of Davis and Mikosh "THE SAMPLE AUTOCORRELATIONS OF HEAVY-TAILED PROCESSES WITH APPLICATIONS TO ARCH". This paper is available, for example, [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-26/issue-5/The-sample-autocorrelations-of-heavy-tailed-processes-with-applications-to/10.1214/aos/1024691368.full).

**Context**: authors use the notation $\varepsilon_\mathbf{x}$ for the Dirac measure at $\mathbf{x}$. Then they use the notation of $\varepsilon_{P_i}$ to denote the Poisson point process. In the screenshot below,
$$\gamma_{n, X}(h) = n^{-1} \sum^{n-h}_{t=1} X_t X_{t+h}$$, where $X_t$ is a stochastic process.

I am struggling to understand the **Theorem 3.5**, which is presented below. I have completely no idea, what $P_i$ and $Q^{(h)}_{i,j}$ could mean in this setting in the definition of $V_h$.

[image: Main theorem]

The **Corollary 2.4** is presented below.

[image: Definitions]

**Question:** What could $P_i$ and $Q_{i,j}$ mean in this context (in the definition of $V_h$)? What is the intuition of such a representation, i.e. mean / variance?

Thanks a lot for any comments!